# Does Google Chrome Prerender work with ajax requests

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, prerender

I'm looking to use pre-rendering to speed up a page, using Chrome prerender:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender

I'm wondering does this work with ajax requests? I have a set of links which load in their pages via a jQuery $.get into a modal. I also have a script which creates the prerender tags for those links.

There doesn't seem to be any performance increase on the ajax load though. Prerendering is working (checked with the troubleshooting section in link above) and it seems to speed up standard links, but not the ajax requests.

It might not work in this way, but I can't find any info about it anywhere else.

Comment: Ask this to chrome developers. How can I know? I can only say `No`. read the link that yourself that you have posted. It clearly says it is similar to opening a tab in background only difference is the tab is not shown.

Comment: I'm with the same question, you get a response?
What I found was that only prerender works only with 1 link and that goes for all open tabs. (Which is the first request)